# turtlebot_rviz_launchers without running turtlebot

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to simulate a turtlebot, because the batteries for my turtlebot were not delivered and I'm waiting for them now.
Running a Gazebo world works fine with the following line: `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`

However, when I try to run Rviz with the following line: `roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch`

It gives me an error that says: `[view_robot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_rviz_launchers] nor is [turtlebot_rviz_launchers] a launch file name`

What is the reason for this? Do I have to install the packages in some way or do I need a running turtlebot in order to run Rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271095/turtlebot_rviz_launchers-without-running-turtlebot/) by [stijndelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30093/stijndelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question comes up quite often. A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=roscd%3A+No+such+package%2Fstack+site%3Aanswers.ros.org) will give you numerous results:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/65003/roscd-no-such-packagestack-beginner_tutorials/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/65950/roscd-returns-roscd-no-such-packagestack-package_name/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/239650/roscd-not-woring/

to name the first few results. The way that I search for solutions to problems is by adding `site:answers.ros.org` to my query (for Google at least) so my query looks like this:

```
<error> site:answers.ros.org
```

(where `<error>` is the error that you're encountering) and I can usually find a solution on the first page of the results.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1